# Native script search bar

Tags: javascript, listview, nativescript

I am new to native script and javascript. I am trying to add search bar for a list. The keyword will be searched from listview. I am able to add search bar and get it's submit event. I checked tns module of searchbar but I am not getting how can I access it's method in my JS file and render new list view according to search keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have referenced the search-bar module:

```
var searchBarModule = require("ui/search-bar");
```

and instanciated it:

```
var searchBar = new searchBarModule.SearchBar();
```

You need to create a listener for the submitEvent, in which is recieved the search as a part of the argument:

```
searchBar.on(searchBarModule.SearchBar.submitEvent, function (args) {
    console.log("Search for " + args.object.text);
    //you can use the search text for what you want
});
```

You can use the `args.object.text` to do a search in your list and pass the parameters to render the list, or, if you are using a two-way data bindings, you need to just update the model.

If you need more info about the searchBarModule, you can find it at the [API reference](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/search-bar/SearchBar.html)

Comment: you saved my day :) btw, the structure of args.object is all but clear from the docs. where did you find that text property was the one to retrieve?

Comment: @dragonmnl Chrome Dev Tools is my friend haha

Comment: can you be more precise please? how can you use Chrome Dev Tools since Nativescript apps are deployed to native? (I know that for hybrid apps, e.g. Ionic, I can remotely inspect)

Comment: @dragonmnl I was using Dev Tools, but I meant to say only chrome, as a joke. There is all you need at the API reference documents: https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/search-bar/SearchBar.html

Comment: now I saw it indeed. For same reason just that 'text' I couldn't find it. However some times it's not so easy to find things in {N} docs

Comment: I don't get the negative votes. If someone would care to explain them I could fix it.

Comment: Can you please explain how can we implement that? I found it in the documentation but there not a good explanation of how to implement it?

Comment: @sabri The code shown should be quite self-explanatory. What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @sailens sorry for disturbing, I am new in mobile developing and I was expecting to see a XML tag or something like that, sorry guys, totally clear now :)

Comment: @sabri Don't worry, we are here to help :)

Comment: @sailens +1 from me with love :D